# with clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to get below expected result with WITH clause in Oracle.

```
Sample Data
Id          C_Symbol    C_Id
1001        DD          201
1001        VR          202
1002        VR          203
1002        AS          205
1002        QA          206
1003        DD          207
1003        QA          208
1004        AS          209
1004        QA          210
```

Expected

```
Id          IS_DD   C_Id(min c_id for each id)
1001        Y       201
1002        N       203
1003        Y       207
1004        N       209
```

Meaning: If any id contains DD in c_symbol it should return flag Y with min c_id.

I tried to achieve this with WITH clause but it doesn't help.

```
WITH A_Info As
    (Select id, c_symbol, c_id from XYZ),
    DD_Info As
    (select id, (case when c_symbol = 'DD' then 'Y' else 'N' END As MD), 
    row_number() over(partition by a_id order by c_id) as RN)
select * from DD_info where RN = 1;
```

This executes row wise, so looking for some alternate solution.
Thank you,

Comment: Is the logic supposed to be that *any* symbol for an ID is 'DD', or only if the symbol for the lowest `c_id` is DD?  What should the flag value be for 1001 if the symbols for the first two rows were swapped, so you had VR/201 and DD/202?

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes, If any ID has c_symbol 'DD' that should return 'Y' else 'N' and min c_id of respective ID

Comment: OK, that isn't really any clearer, but it seems like you still want the flag to be 'Y' in that scenario. Perhaps: "If an ID has any `c_id` with its `c_symbol` set to DD then 'Y', else 'N'; plus the lowest `c_id` for that ID"? Editing your question to have better sample data and results would really help make this clearer. But if that's correct, then Gordon Linoff's aggregation/case approach does what you want, right?

Comment: yes, Gordon's post helped me to solve m problem.

Comment: Then [see what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center. If that answer solved your problem then please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when c_symbol = 'DD' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as is_dd,
       min(c_id) as c_id
from sample
group by id;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/QOA21847) is an example.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that really helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: I would like to know how this statement works here
max(case when c_symbol = 'DD' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as is_dd